# XAML/MVVMx Problems with binding custom Array of object to a Grid

Tags: xamarin, binding, grid, mvvmcross

I try to bind an Object with custom Text for testing to my GridView and can't really get the solution.

I already tried to get it rolling with `Grid.BindingContext` but it won't work.

Can someone help me out here?

```xml
<Grid>
<Grid.BindingContext>
<x:Array Type="{x:Type clients:MinRepresentation}<clients:MinRepresentation Id="123456789" PlannedStartTime="01-01-2019" PlannedEndTime="01-12-2019"  />
</x:Array>
</Grid.BindingContext>


<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0,10,0,5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BackgroundColor="#CC3F6E3F">
<Image Source="{helpers:ImageResource catkinApp.UI.Images.state_new.png}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
<Label Text="{Binding ID, StringFormat='ID: [{0}]'}" FontSize="Small" Margin="5,0,10,0" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#FFFFFF"/>
<Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="(In Bearbeitung)" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you want to bind custom object for Grid.BindingContext, you don't need to use Array, you just do like this:

```
 public class model1
{
    public string str1 { get; set; }
    public string str2 { get; set; }
}

 <Grid>
        <Grid.BindingContext>
            <local:model1 str1="aaaa" str2="bbbb"></local:model1>
        </Grid.BindingContext>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="this is test, please take a look!" />
            <Label
                Margin="5,0,10,0"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="Small"
                Text="{Binding str1}"
                TextColor="#FFFFFF" />
            <Label
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="Small"
                Text="{Binding str2}"
                TextColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

Here is the article from MSDN, you can take a look:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/string-formatting

Comment: Thank you, i copied the code from my listview and totaly forgot to delete the array...